# Where in the Bible does it say "I will destroy those who destroy My land"?

Tags: judgment, reference-request

Where in the Bible does it say "I (God) will destroy those who destroy My land"?

Comment: This question: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/9208/1039 can tell you how to answer your own question much more easily

Comment: By the way, you have "[the sweetest name I know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YIan96NyCw)"

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: @AffableGeek Yes, but that advice works better when you actually have the proper text, not a paraphrase like this one. While I agree that this is referring to Jer. 16:18, that verse isn't mentioned in most of the Google results I find searching the page. Heck, searching the exact phrase only finds this question and something about Israelis finding a cure for ALS.

Comment: Was asked [here](http://bible-christian.org/discussion/response227.html) as well.

Comment: Seen your comment to @MattGutting. [This](http://restoringeden.org/resources/bibleverses) also led me to [Rev 11:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+11%3A18&version=RSVCE).

Comment: Perhaps an attempt at paraphrasing 1 Corinthians 3:17 ?

Comment: I believe you are talking about Revelation 11:18.

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of Jeremiah 16:18:

> I will repay them double for their wickedness and their sin, because they have defiled my land with the lifeless forms of their vile images and have filled my inheritance with their detestable idols.

(NIV)

That's the closest thing I was able to come up with on a [BibleHub.com](http://biblehub.net/search.php?q=%22my+land%22) search.

Comment: Hi God bless you, thanks for your help. Another brother told me Revelation 11;18 "...& should destroy those who destroy the earth". A long time ago I remember reading something similar to "before man destroys the earth I (God) will intervene..." I will keep searching, Gbu.